# Rails getting the count from a deep association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

I am trying to count how many times a redirect has been done from a retailer product. What would the best way to do this?

I have tried to use: `@products.includes(:retailer_products).includes(:redirects).count("redirects.id")}`

I have been able to get the count for a singular product, but i would like to get the count based on all products.

A `product` has a `retailer`, which in turn has `retailer products`. Each `retailer product` has `redirects` which contain the `retailer_product_id`, and the date it was clicked - `created_at`.

*Note: Some products do not have a retailer product, so wouldn't have any redirects associated to them.*

**product model**

```
has_many :retailer_products
has_many :retailers, through: :retailer_products
```

**retailer_product model**

```
has_many :redirects
```

**redirect model**

```
belongs_to :retailer_product
```

Comment: So you want the number of redirects connected with specific products via `retailer_products`, right? And `RetailerProduct` belongs to `project`, right?

Comment: That is correct. I have been able to get the retailer products for a single product, its just the redirect count for all products. Some products dont have a retailer_product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try the other way, you're interested in `Redirect` count after all:

```
Redirect.joins(:retailer_product)
        .where(retailer_products: { product_id: @products.pluck(:id) })
```

Comment: Dammit, Yes!! Cheers mate you are a life saver. This worked a treat. I didn't think of it like that.